# cannot able to update my GMsmapView when call a funtion

Tags: swift

**Code**

```
  import UIKit
  import GooglePlaces
  import GoogleMaps

  class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var mapsView: GMSMapView!


var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
var searchController: UISearchController?
var pick:UISearchController!
var drop:UISearchController!
var marker:GMSMarker!


var cgrectfordrop:CGRect?
var resultView: UITextView?


var gmspick:GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!
var gmsdrop:GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.mapsView=mapView




    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self





    gmspick=GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    gmspick.delegate=self
    gmspick.accessibilityLabel="picku"
    pick=UISearchController(searchResultsController: gmspick)
    pick.searchResultsUpdater = gmspick
    pick.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    pick.searchBar.accessibilityIdentifier="picku"
    pick.searchBar.placeholder="Enter pick up location"
    pick.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    pick.searchBar.sizeToFit()






    gmsdrop=GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    gmsdrop.delegate=self
    gmsdrop.accessibilityLabel="dropu"
    drop=UISearchController(searchResultsController: gmsdrop)
    drop.searchResultsUpdater = gmsdrop
    drop.searchBar.placeholder="Enter drop location"
    drop.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    drop.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    drop.searchBar.sizeToFit()







   let pickyvalue=view.frame.height/2- 
    pick.searchBar.frame.height/2
       // cgrectfordrop=CGRect(x: 0, y: pickyvalue/3.9, width: 
   view.frame.width, height: 45.0)
        let subViewpick = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: pickyvalue/9, 
    width: view.frame.width, height: 45.0))
        subViewpick.addSubview(pick.searchBar)
        view.addSubview(subViewpick)




     let dropyvalue=view.frame.height/2-drop.searchBar.frame.height/2
    //  cgrectfordrop=CGRect(x: 0, y: dropyvalue/11, width: 
     view.frame.width, height: 45.0)
     let subViewpickd = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: dropyvalue/3, 
     width: view.frame.width, height: 45.0))
      subViewpickd.addSubview(drop.searchBar)
    view.addSubview(subViewpickd)



  }
   func settingmarker(location:CLLocationCoordinate2D){


    self.mapsView.animate(toLocation: location)


   }
}













  extension FirstViewController: 
 GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
func resultsController(_ resultsController: 
 GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    if (resultsController.accessibilityLabel=="picku") {
        pick.isActive=false
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        print("pickup")

     settingmarker(location: place.coordinate)

    }else if(resultsController.accessibilityLabel=="dropu"){
        drop.isActive=false
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        print("dropu")

    }


}

func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

}

Cannot abble to update my Gmsmapview when calling setting marker function
Cannot abble to update my Gmsmapview when calling setting marker functionCannot abble to update my Gmsmapview when calling setting marker function
Cannot abble to update my Gmsmapview when calling setting marker function
Cannot abble to update my Gmsmapview when calling setting marker function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this part

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
self.mapsView = mapView
```

with

```
self.mapsView.camera = camera
```

assigning the map will make it `nil`  , as you declared it as `weak` while it's an outlet

Comment: why it makes  the map view nil

Comment: as i said because it's `weak` , also you set zero frame which will make it not visible also

Comment: how it affects by setting my outlet as weak?

Comment: your `mapsView` will be nil after that assignment , so you won't see anything

Comment: can you tell me how to remove specific set of markers in GMS maps

Comment: for example can i do like this var hs=GMSMARKER() . iwant to clear hs only in mapsview

Comment: do `hs.map = nil`